# Single board computers and screens power noise susceptibility

Tags: noise, grounding, mains, sbc

I have setups of some (five to ten) Raspberry Pi 2 or Raspberry Pi 3 single board computers running the same amount of screens. All computers and screens are connected to a single mains phase, splitting on the last meters (eg. a single or few multi outlet power strips).

The computers are connected to the screens by HDMI wires of 1-2m length each.

While on a bench top, a single or some of these computers run perfectly, they often fail randomly to boot in this kind of installation, when the power is switched on centrally.
Their power LED is lit, but nothing else happens. About one of ten screens is off by random, eg. some starts are perfect, but some show one or even more screens off by the respective computer not booting.

Different brands of power supply used for the computers give different reliability it seems, but it never gets perfect. The low voltage wires usually are 1-2m long.

Power supply for the screens usually is integrated, sometimes using grounding contacts, sometimes not, depending on the make.

So I suspect ground loops or other electric noise issues on switching all these devices at the same time is causing the computers to fail boot.

Is there any canonical way to maybe measure and solve this problem?

[image: block diagram]

Comment: "Is there any canonical way to maybe measure and solve this problem?" I would start by drawing a block diagram. Not only could it help you to see the problem, but it will also help people here understand the situation.

Comment: Not canonical, but when we experience similar issues with SBC's and embedded monitors, we discovered that use of ferrite beads/rings on the SBC and Display IO was a cheap, easy, and reliable solution.  Also power-up sequencing of teh SBC and monitor (intentional or not) can confuse SBC boot depending on how intelligent (or not) the hardware is.

Comment: Added a simple diagram